# Turning .txt files into matrices in python

Tags: file, python-3.x, matrix

So, I have .txt files with matrices in this form:

```
5 8
9 -1
0 2
```

file2:

```
9 2 -1
7 0 9
-1 7 0
```

and so on, the dimensions are not set in stone. 
What I'm trying to do is to create a function that translates the text documents into matrices and later no is capable of doing basic math with said matrices, namely multiplication.

My code is already capable of opening the matrices and reading them to some extent like so:

```
Matrix = {}
file = open(filename, 'r')
for line in file:
    width = len(line.split(" "))
    height += 1
matrixname = input("enter matrix name")
for line in file:
    Matrix[matrixname] = [[0 for x in range(height)] for y in range(width)]
```

but I'm not sure if I'm going into the right direction or what I'm able to do now.

Edit* 
juanpa's suggested code piece

```
[[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in tiedosto]
```

does the job of handling each index value one by one and I now have a function that will create a matrix of zeros that is the same dimension as the original matrix, now what I lack is a way to put each index value into their correspondent matrix index of the matrix of zeros.

Comment: Why don't you just build the matrix from the text file directly, and not get the width and height first to build a list with all zeros, where presumably you will iterate over the file again to populate the list with other values?

Comment: All you really need is something like `[[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in file]`

Comment: Is this doable without having numpy?

Comment: Do you see any numpy in that code???

Comment: Well, what I mean is that I'm not sure how to use the line of code. I did manage to make a matrix of zeros by using the width and height I got from my first loop, though. How can I build around your piece of code to use the "i" of it? I did try it with debug and the i is getting the proper value of each matrix index value.

Comment: That is all the code you need. Basically delete everything after you open the file and put that line of code. Well, assign it to a variable of course, or a dictionary like you seem to want to do. But not in a for-loop.

Comment: Just forget about the matrix of zeroes. It's useless.

Comment: That's works - thanks